# Установка Ejudge На Windows 10

Tags: php, c++, phpmyadmin

Здравстуйте, недавно захотел установить тестирующую систему ejudge на свой комп...мне посаветовали скачать с инета Операционную систему сразу с установленной тестируюзей системой....но я хотел бы устновить его на винду 10 на свой комп....опишите пожалуйста полную установку новейщей версии ejudge на винду 10..

Answer (score 1):

FAQ с оффициального сайта производителя https://ejudge.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_ejudge, вот еще установка с хабра https://habrahabr.ru/post/249293/